# "error: add_cacheinfo failed to refresh for path" with custom power shell merge driver

Tags: git, powershell, encoding, merge

I'm trying to write a custom git merge driver in power shell but I already fail at "doing nothing". That is opening the local file, writing the content back to it as the merge result and returning an exit code of 0.

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$baseFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$localFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$remoteFile
)

$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'

(Get-Content $localFile) | Out-File $localFile
exit 0
```

To the .git/config I added:

```
[merge "custom"]
    name = custom powershell merge driver
    driver = c:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command ./mergeDriver.ps1 -baseFile %O -localFile %A -remoteFile %B
```

And the .gitattributes looks like this:

```
*.txt text
file.txt merge=custom
```

With file.txt being a utf8 text file to merge.

Every time I try to merge/cherry-pick the file with conflicts I get `error: add_cacheinfo failed to refresh for path 'file.txt'; merge aborting.`

**Example repository**

I create a test repository at https://bitbucket.org/Deeem2031/mergedriver_test/src/master/
If you clone it and add the change to .git/config you should be able to reproduce the problem by running `git cherry-pick dbb40ba`

**Things I already noticed**

If you remove `$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'` or don't touch the file at all i.e. remove `(Get-Content $localFile) | Out-File $localFile` the error is gone.

It doesn't seem to matter if file.txt is utf8 encoded beforehand or not.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file does state `Input objects are automatically formatted as they would be in the terminal, [...]` which does imply it might change things but the only difference I can see (even with a hex-editor) is a added CRLF at the end of the file.

I did find this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65967910/6308948 which does sound very similar to my problem but I'm already writing my result to $localFile.

So the obvious question: Why does this error happen?

Comment: I don't know anything about PowerShell, but in general, any attempt to read from file *f* while also writing *to* file *f* is ... fraught. That is, in general, you would want to do the get-content step first, wait for it to complete, and only *then* begin writing to `$localFile`, lest the writing-to destroy the data before the reading-from is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually in the merge driver, i.e. `mergeDriver.ps1`.

Git's contract is that the file contents received, and written, by the merge driver are in the "clean" form, i.e. in your case with LF-only (or at least without CR/LF) line endings.

However, `(Get-Content $localFile) | Out-File $localFile` does not leave the file contents unchanged, despite how it might look like. The reason is that `$localFile` has no line ending at all in your case. `hexdump -C` says this about its contents:

```
00000000  ef bb bf 76 65 72 73 69  6f 6e 20 3d 20 31 35 30  |...version = 150|
```

And `Out-File` *appends a CR/LF*!

So if you change your merge driver to call `Out-File -NoNewline` instead, it will work without that `add_cacheinfo` error message.

That is, it will work as intended: that `cherry-pick` will say that nothing was changed, and ask you if you want to commit nevertheless (which would require the `--allow-empty` option).

Comment: This does clarify the problem and solves the issue with the above example. The only thing I had to add was using `((Get-Content $localFile) -join "\`n") + "\`n" | Set-Content -NoNewline $localFile` so I can handle multiline "file.txt"s which is based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48919146/6308948
Thanks